# Create a Report using Salesforce SOAP or REST API

Tags: api, reporting, rest, soap, new

I know about [Salesforce Reports and Dashboards REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_intro.htm).
But Report REST API allows only to change (update) an existing report by sending PATCH request with appropriate json body and clone a report based on existing one by sending POST request.
But I need to create a new Report, not cloned report.

Also I tested dashboard creation by sending POST request with appropriate json body on the url **https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/analytics/dashboards** and it works. But the same doesn't work for the Report. After sending POST request on the url **ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/analytics/reports** I got a response:

```
[
  {
    "errorCode": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": "The clone request must contain a valid cloneId parameter."
  }
]
```

It means that I cannot create new Report by sending POST request to the REST resource.

Also I tried to create report by upsert and insert methods of SOAP Partner API, but in the response result I got the next message:

```
<message>entity type cannot be updated: Report</message>
<statusCode>CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY</statusCode>
```

My goal is to deploy personal report to the instance.
I already successfully deployed reports which are located in the custom folder or Unfiled Public Reports folder. I have done this with by deploy() method of the Salesforce SOAP API.
But in the instance there is a standard folder My Personal Reports. And it impossible to deploy personal report via deploy() method of the SOAP API, because of unknown api name of the My Personal Reports folder.
I retrieved metadata of the personal report in json format using Salesforce Reports and Dashboards REST API, but I don't know how to create a personal report based on the retrieved json metadata of this report.

If anyone know how to solve this problem (may be there is any workaround to create a personal report), please, share your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [Salesforce Reports and Dashboards API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_report_example_post_report.htm) has been expanded since you last checked. It is definitely possible to create a report into your personal folder as of 30SEP19. I suggest that you review current documentation.

- You can create a new report with the [Salesforce Reports and Dashboards API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_report_example_post_report.htm) via POST request to `/services/data/v39.0/analytics/reports`.
- Specify a desired folder ID for the new report inside `reportMetadata` object, e.g. `"folderId" : "005R0000000Kg8cIAC"`